# Coding probability?

Tags: combinatorics

Given $s,t\in(0,1)$, $c>1$, $n\in\Bbb N$, pick $2^{n^t}$ random vectors $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^{2^{n^t}}$ such that each $v_i\in\{x\in\{0,1\}^{2^n}:|x|_{hamming}={2^{n-n^s}}\}$.

If $v_i^\perp$ is projection of first $2^{n/c}$ coordinates of each $v_i$, then what is probability that there is a vector $v$ in $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^{2^{n^t}}$ such that $|v_i^\perp|_{hamming}<2^{n/cd}$ holds with some real $d>1$?